# How can I invoke a Monad function directly?

Tags: haskell, monads

In the example below, I'd like to be able to call the 'ls' function directly (see the last commented out line of the example) but I have not been able to figure out the correct syntax.
Thanks in advance.

```
module Main (main) where

import System.Directory

ls :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
ls dir = do
    fileList <- getDirectoryContents dir
    return fileList

main = do
    fileList <- ls "."
    mapM putStrLn fileList 
    -- How can I just use the ls call directly like in the following (which doesn't compile)?
    -- mapM putStrLn (ls".")
```

Comment: Is `mapM_ putStrLn =<< ls "."` what you're after?

Comment: Why not `ls = getDirectoryContents`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't just use

```
mapM putStrLn (ls ".")
```

because `ls "."` has type `IO [FilePath]`, and `mapM putStrLn` expects just `[FilePath]`, so you need to use bind, or `>>=` in Haskell. So your actual line would be

```
main = ls "." >>= mapM_ putStrLn
```

Notice the `mapM_` function, not just `mapM`. `mapM` will give you `IO [()]` type, but for `main` you need `IO ()`, and that's what `mapM_` is for.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. I don't totally understand it yet (I haven't seen '>>=' yet but I'll look into it now). It's an interesting challenge to start learning a language like Haskell after 35 years of structured and OO programming but I'm convinced it's worth the effort even though I'm stuck with a lot of "baby" questions.